# Cordova file transfer: Cannot view image after upload to aws s3

Tags: cordova, amazon-s3

Im working with cordova file transfer to upload images to my s3 bucket.

I mange to upload the file without any errors, and its even visable as a file in s3.

But when I try to download the image from s3, I can't view it (image is corrupted)
when doing `file image.png` im getting a result that it is a data file and not an image..

here is the upload code:

```
let transfer = new Transfer();
options = {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'image/jpg',
  },
  httpMethod: 'PUT',
  chunkedMode: false
};
console.log("URL, ", url)
return transfer.upload(fileUrl, url, options, true)
```

I tried with or without `encodeURI` method, with or without `chunkmode`
nothing seems to work. any ideas?

Ps this code uses ionic native library but i also tried go strait to the `FileTransfer` object and it still didnt work

Im also using a singed url that im getting from my web server pre uploading

UPDATE: 
here is the code that i used with the native `FileTransfer` object

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.headers = { 'Content-type': 'image/jpg' }
options.httpMethod =  'PUT';
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.mimeType = 'image/jpg';

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, url, onSuccess, onFail, options, true);
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried out using the file transfer object?

Comment: @genadhi in the question

Comment: i guess it should be mime type setting in options object. check out this link for more info - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: @Gandhi i tried with mime type... got some thing

Comment: did it work finally?

Comment: @Gandhi no, same problem with mimeType: image/jpg

Comment: could you post the updated code that you tried?

Comment: @Gandhi updated in the question

Comment: i guess the mime type is 'image/jpeg' not 'image/jpg' Could you check with this change?

Comment: @Gandhi same thing. Im not sure where is the problem since the image is being uploaded, I can see it on my s3 bucket, but i cannot view it.

Comment: If you are unable to see the file, you cannot guarantee that its uploaded properly

Comment: @Gandhi of course.. there is some kind of a problem during the upload process, I also tried uploading the image via postman. and everything is working, so the problem is not with s3

Comment: Exactly. We need to track down the upload problem. Are you testing on device? Any console errors?

Comment: @Gandhi testing on android 6.0. no errors on `adb logcat` i even see there that the response from the s3 server is 200

Comment: @Gandhi Ok this is funny! the problem was the `content-type` header I did `Content-type` and with `Content-Type` its working!

Comment: Glad it worked. Cheers

Comment: Just had the same issue. `Content-Type` solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `Content-type` header

`Content-Type` instead of `Content-type` solved the problem

Answer (score -2):

I am posting images to my server with cordova file transfer. Here is my code:

```
function uploadPicture(url_to_upload_php_handler, fileURI){

    var uri = encodeURI(url_to_upload_php_handler);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey="fileUpload";
    options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode=false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(fileURI, uri, uploadSuccess, uploadFail, options);
}
```