# ngCordova FileTransfer direct upload to AWS S3 WebKitFormBoundary Issue

Tags: node.js, cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload a file using a pre-signed url on AWS-S3 with ngCordova FileTransfer Plugin.

I am successfully able to upload files to AWS-S3 but the content of the file contain

`------WebKitFormBoundarylCFgJXqqECF1rJ2m
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="75cae09191bd92a16c3ff05baeb88b9b.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg`

Due to which the image file can't be opened. 
How can i get rid of this header in my file. I have an idea that if i put a binary data instead of form data it will get rid of this as i have tested it in POSTMAN but couldn't find any way to do that in cordova file transfer.

```
 $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(s3SignedUrl, imagePathOnPhone, {
                                fileKey: "file",
                                fileName: localFileName,
                                httpMethod: "PUT",
                                mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
                            })
                                .then(function (result) {
                                    console.log(result);

                                }, function (error) {
                                    console.log(error);

                                }, function (progress) {
                                    console.log(progress);

                                });
```

My Bucket is in Frankfurt region and api v4. and i am using nodejs on server.

Comment: Try adding "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" to the opts to disable multipart.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/855def11c3c35df6f9de10ccca46e7336baa2506/tests/tests.js#L1273-1276 https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-with-upload-headers-and-progress-events-android-and-ios-only

Comment: i tried it with no luck.

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi I would suggest you to set the content type attribute in header and send the same during upload. SUggest you to check the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025867/name-of-picture-uploaded-with-file-phonegap-plugin-imagea3456/ where we got it working

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi Also the official cordova file transfer page - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer clearly states the following : headers: A map of header name/header values. Use an array to specify more than one value. On iOS, FireOS, and Android, if a header named Content-Type is present, multipart form data will NOT be used. (Object)  I hope setting content type in header should help you out

Comment: @Gandhi It works fine if i upload to our own server, i can read the content of the request and save the image only.  The issue is how can i handle that while uploading directly to S3. S3 save the whole form data. where as i want to save image only.

Comment: @Rasikh will hav  check on that. But try once setting content type in header

Comment: @Gandhi i have checked it already. It didn't work. i have changed implementation for now. i am uploading to my server first and upload it to AWS from my server. But it would be ideal if i upload directly to S3.

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi Suggest you to look at this link where we resolved the exact similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555478/cordova-file-transfer-cannot-view-image-after-upload-to-aws-s3 If possible try out vanilla cordova file transfer plugin once.

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `Content-Type` property to the `params` section.

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(s3SignedUrl, imagePathOnPhone, {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: localFileName,
    httpMethod: "PUT",
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    params: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    }
})
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);

}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);

}, function (progress) {
    console.log(progress);

});
```

Comment: It should be `options` instead of `params`.

Comment: Nope, the third value in the constructor is already the `options` object. See docs - upload(server, targetPath, options,...) - at http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/ or a practicle example at http://www.gajotres.net/using-cordova-file-transfer-plugin-with-ionic-framework/

Comment: @daan.desmedt Should be set in options like this: options = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
  },
  httpMethod: 'PUT',
  chunkedMode: false
};

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"` to the `opts.headers` to disable multipart:

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(s3SignedUrl, imagePathOnPhone, {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: localFileName,
    httpMethod: "PUT",
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    }
})
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
}, function (progress) {
    console.log(progress);
});
```

Comment: i am gonna try that tomorrow. i will update you with my findings