# Image upload not working in Cordova

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I am using Cordova file upload plugin to upload image. I am trying to upload image from gallery to server but the file is not uploading to server.

Here is the js code.

```
function uploadImage() {
    document.getElementById('picture_msg').innerHTML = "";
    // Get URI of picture to upload
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(uri) {
            try {
                // Pick image from div
                 var img = document.getElementById('pimage');
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
                img.style.display = "block";
                var imageURI = uri;
                if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {
                    document.getElementById('picture_msg').innerHTML = "Tap on picture to select image from gallery.";
                    return;
                }
                // Verify server has been entered
                server = document.getElementById('server').value;
                server = 'http://domain_name/mobile_app/img_upload.php';
                console.log("Server "+server);
                if (server) {
                    // Specify transfer options
                    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                    options.fileKey="file";
                    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
                    options.chunkedMode = false;

                    // Transfer picture to server
                    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                    ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
                        document.getElementById('picture_msg').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";
                        img.src = uri;
                        img.width = 100;
                        img.height = 100;
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        document.getElementById('picture_msg').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;
                    }, options);
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('picture_msg').innerHTML = "Server Not Found";
                }
            }
            catch(exce) {
                alert(exce);
            }
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
            document.getElementById('picture_msg').innerHTML = "No Image Found";
        },
        {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
    );
}
```

And here is the img_upload.php code.

```
 print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "mobile_app/".$new_image_name);
```

I tried this as well.

```
$dirname = "user_img/"; 
 // If uploading file
 if ($_FILES) {
    print_r($_FILES);
  //  mkdir ($dirname, 0777, true);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 }
```

I am getting upload successful message but when I check the data on server it is showing empty. No files are there.

Please advise what am I doing wrong here.

**Edit**

It seems like problem with PHP file. path in webserver is `/public_html/app/user_imgs`

My PHP file **img_upload.php** is under app folder.

Comment: Any error on device console? Are you testing in the actual device?

Comment: no error on device console. i m testing it in device. not on emulator.

Comment: Try getting response from the server like `alert(r.response);`

Comment: @CalculatingMachine i came across a similar post a while back where the user was able to mae it work. Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555478/cordova-file-transfer-cannot-view-image-after-upload-to-aws-s3

Comment: @Gandhi i will check the question again and let you know.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: i am getting Array() in alert(r.response).

Comment: Please update your array details into question

Comment: I didn't created any array. it seems like $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. This could be the reason for Array() output.